# How to compare two object of same beans to see the difference

Tags: java, equals

I have a bean class say User.java

```
class User{
String a;
String b
String c;
...
}
```

how i use it in code,

```
function foo1(){

User u = new User();
//Getting data from DB and adding it to user class say
u.setA("a");
u.setC("c");
foo2(u)
}


function foo2(User u){

User u1 = new User();
//Getting data from another DB and adding it to user class say
u1.setA("a");
u1.setB("b");

//Compare it here,
Boolean status = u1.equals(u);
u1.toString().equals(u.toString());
}
```

I noticed that `u1.equals(u);` returns true and `u1.toString().equals(u.toString())` return false,

Can any one please explain it that what is the difference between both comparisons and which is batter to use. I just need to compare if both the beans are same or not(with respect to data).

what if i use `u1 == u` ... ???
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
public String toString() {
    return this.getA() + "\t" + this.getB() + "\t" + this.getC() + "\t";
}

private boolean equals(String a, String b) {
    // check for both being null
    if (a == null && b == null)
        return true;
    // check for only one of them to be null
    if ((a == null && b != null) || (a != null && b == null))
        return false;
    // check for equals()
    return a.trim().equals(b.trim());
}

public boolean equals(User user) {
    return equals(this.a, user.getA()) && equals(this.b, user.getB())
            && equals(this.c, user.getC());
}
```

Comment: You are accessing another method local variable, It's won't compile even, and post User class `equals()`, `toString()` methods method

Comment: This code is to explain the idea only. Please ignore the compile time errors,

Comment: Post the toString, equlas() methods here

Comment: Thanks @KugathasanAbimaran i got your point, i checked the both functions and got my problem. actually i was expecting that system is using the equles/toString from object class, but i noticed after your comment that it was overwritten, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Please see the edited code with equal and toString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `==` is a reference comparison, ie using memory location to decide equality. If both do not contain the same reference, it will return false.

Calling `equals` on an object instance will use the implementation of `equals` in that class; if it doesn't have one that overrides the default, it falls back to the generic one in `Object`. This is the `Object.equals` description from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

In short if you don't implement your own `equals` method you'll get the default behavior which will behave just like `==`. For details on writing your own `equals` method, check this [very comprehensive community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).